# Usar innerHTML correctamente en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Recién hice esta pregunta en el foro en inglés y me pusieron puntos negativos, la verdad no comprendo el motivo, quizá mi inglés no es bueno y no comprendieron la pregunta.

Necesito pasar el siguiente código HTML a JavaScript, he leído y se que se usa el método `getElementById` conjuntamente con la propiedad `innerHTML`, pero no tengo la experiencia y conocimientos para hacerlo.

Para los que deseen usar este código HTML, se usa para crear un botón de donaciones de Paypal, obviamente el certificado encriptado no les funcionará deben de crearlo desde la web de Paypal.

**CODIGO HTML:**

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
            <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_XC/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"><img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_XC/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

**CODIGO JAVASCRIPT:**

De esta forma funciona correctamente, pero se que no es técnicamente la forma de hacerlo:

```
document.getElementById('paypal_donate').innerHTML = '<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank"><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"><input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----"><input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_XC/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"><img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_XC/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"></form>';
```

En mi HTML objetivo tengo: `<div id="paypal_donate" style=" overflow: hidden;">...</div>`
Necesito rellenar esos tres puntos con el form y los inputs que compartí en el código HTML de arriba usando   `document.getElementById('paypal_donate').innerHTML` de JavaScript correctamente.

Alguien que comprenda la pregunta y me ayude con esto o si les parece que está mal formulada por favor comenten no me pongan puntos negativos sin decirme el motivo.

Muy agradecido,
Juan

Comment: El sitio en ingles es mas *estricto* supongo que, si es la misma, venga de que no queda del todo claro que deseas hacer, ¿Quieres indexar código desde javascript sin usar innerHTML? necesitamos más contexto para comprender que deseas hacer, también te comento que puedes ocultar, mostrar elementos html desde javascript con el uso de css, asi puedes evitar el uso de innerHTML

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta original y agregué más datos para clarificar la misma, también he propuesto modificar mi HTML objetivo para quede así: `<div id="paypal_donate" style=" overflow: hidden;">...</div>` De esta forma lo que falta rellenar donde están los "..." es el form y los inputs.  Quiero usar innerHTML pero no tengo la experiencia adecuada para hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no es técnicamente la forma de usarlo? Tu solución es sencilla y correcta.

Comment: Me pregunto lo mismo que @Bettylex. ¿Qué entiendes por *técnicamente correcto*? Sería bueno quizá que expliques de dónde sacas al `form`, porque la seguridad podría estar comprometida y es un tema que debería ser tratado si otros usuarios/fuentes pueden intervenir en la obtención del formulario.

Comment: Bien les respondo a ambos, soy principiante y he visto que otros colegas en lugar de copiar el código HTML textual dentro de dos comillas simples usan otra forma creando por ejemplo una variable. Supongamos en el caso de un HREF: `<div id="ir_google"><a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Ir a Google</a></div>` En lugar de usar En lugar de `document.getElementById('ir_google').innerHTML = '<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Ir a Google</a>` que sería el método que usé yo.

Comment: Usan: `document.getElementById('ir_google').innerHTML = ''
var a = document.getElementById('ir_google')
.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
a.href = 'https://google.com';
a.target = "_blank";
a.rel = "noopener noreferrer";
a.textContent = 'Ir a Google';`

Comment: Con respecto a la pregunta de @A.Cedano del `form` ese código lo otorga Paypal para ser usado en un HTML normal que lo puede ver cualquiera. Solo que yo en lugar de ponerlo en el HTML lo invoco desde JavaScript, pero es lo mismo en cuanto a seguridad supongo.

Comment: Hay muchas formas de hacer esto mismo, `.innerHTML` es una de ellas y ciertamente es "tecnicamente correcto" como lo estás haciendo. Si estás interesado en saber si esto constituye una buena práctica, la respuesta es: Depende. Y depende quizá de cuestiones que no están presentes en la pregunta. Como regla general, yo evitaría introducir código de esta manera, pero si no queda otra no lo veo mal.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @Emeeus por lo que veo está bien así como lo hice.

Comment: Mira, la diferencia entre tu código y el de tus amigos, es que ellos vuelcan el HTML en un nuevo elemento creado, y después lo introducen en el contenedor como un nuevo hijo. Esto permite que se conserve el contenido que hubiera antes de meterlo.

Tu código, por contra, introduce todo el HTML directamente dentro, machacando cualquier contenido que hubiera anteriormente.

Comment: Creo que, en este caso, por legibilidad, funcionalidad y economía, tu solución es "mejor" que la de tus compañeros. Diferente sería si el contenedor contuviera otros hijos que quisieras conservar al introducir tu `form`. En ese caso, no tendrías más remedio que emplear la solución de ellos. ;)

Comment: La diferencia entre poner el contenido en una variable o usarlo directamente para el `innerHTML` es casi insignificante, por lo que puedes hacerlo de ambas maneras sin problema. Por lo que debes preocuparte más en casos como estos es porque no ocurran [ataques XSS](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/), por eso mi pregunta en el anterior comentario, ya que si esa posibilidad existiera deberías escribir un código que lo evite, pero no parece ser el caso aquí.

Comment: Exacto @Bettylex en algunos casos tuve que usar ese código que comenté antes porque había contenido que necesitaba que no se machacara para luego usarlo o comparar el valor actual con el nuevo para tomar acciones.  Y tal cual comenta A.Cedano he leído de esos ataques XSS pero al ser código de los developers de Paypal supuse que ellos sabrían lo que hacían.

Answer (score 1):

Bien, luego de recibir varios comentarios de usuarios con experiencia y conocimientos de que mi solución es correcta y sencilla "técnicamente hablando" voy a auto responder mi pregunta así no se alarga más este hilo.
No es necesario que la voten ni me den puntos, es simplemente para dejar terminado este hilo.
Muchas gracias a todos los que comentaron y aportaron aquí.

```
document.getElementById('paypal_donate').innerHTML = '<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank"><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"><input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----"><input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_XC/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"><img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/es_XC/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"></form>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es rellenarlo con codigo HTML inyectado puedes, como has indicado utilizar innerHtml. El string de HTML es el que es, no tienes forma de acortarlo ni nada por el estilo. Sin embargo, esto es bastante chapucero y no debería ser utilizado casi nunca. El codigo generico para inyectar código html en cierto div sería el siguiente:

JS:

```
document.getElementById("id-del-elemento-a-rellenar").innerHtml = "Hola a todos";
```

Si precisas del uso de varias lineas recomiendo usar el acento grave para ello:

```
document.getElementById("id-del-elemento-a-rellenar").innerHtml = `Hola
a
todos`
```

Sin embargo, hay formas más "bonitas" de hacerlo.

### Display

Modificando el valor del display puedes lograr un efecto parecido, haciendo que el contenido de tu div pase de oculto a mostrado, estando siempre presente en el documento.

```
//Esconder un elemento
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
//Mostrar el mismo elemento
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";
```

### Visibility

Es bastante parecido a el Display pero en este caso ocupará espacio en el elemento a pesar de estar escondido.

```
 //Esconder 
 document.getElementById("myDIV").style.visibility = 'hidden';
 //Mostrar
 document.getElementById("myDIV").style.visibility = 'visible';
```

En caso de que sea preciso al 100% inyectar elementos HTML dentro de un elemento a partir de un string de código HTML la única forma de hacerlo es modificando el innerHTML de un elemento existente.

Comment: No entendí tu respuesta, ni lo que afirmas al final de la misma: *En caso de que sea preciso al 100% que los valores de HTML no estén en el DOM hasta que sea preciso cargarlos mediante JS, entonces la única forma que tienes de hacerlo es con innerHTML.* ¿? Se pueden cargar elementos de forma dinámica dependiendo de eventos como clicks en botones, llenado de inputs, etc. `innerHTML` no tiene nada que ver con la carga dinámica, su función es **establecer o devolver sintaxis HTML** nada más.

Comment: Tienes razon, puedes crear elementos mediante js con `document.createElement(tagName, [options]);`, pero a lo que me refería es a que la unica forma que tiene de añadir un string que contenga codigo HTML a un documento HTML es mediante la edición de el innerHTML de un elemento ya existente. Edito mi respuesta para que esté mejor explicada.

Comment: @SebastianCiocarlan el elemento ya existe en el HTML, `<div id="paypal_donate" style=" overflow: hidden;">...</div>`. Eso está puesto en la pregunta e incluso lo agregué al primer comentario que me hizo Nicolas Oñate.

Comment: En resumen ya compartí una solución que funciona, lo único que me pareció "técnicamente poco elegante", pero colegas con más experiencia como @A.Cedano han opinado es mi solución es correcta y sencilla cosa que yo ignoraba antes de realizar la pregunta.